# Differentiability of operator norm

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, differential-operators, matrix-theory

Is there any known results about differentiability properties of the function $\mathbb f:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R,$ $f(t):=\|A+tB\|_{op}$ where $\|.\|_{op}$ denotes the usual operator norm of the matrices acting on finite dimensional complex Hilbert spaces?

Comment: note that the operator norm, restricted to diagonal matrices, is just the max norm.

Comment: Maybe this question should be migrated to math.stackexchange.con.

Comment: @DeaneYang I don't think it needs to go to MSE because of the level of the question, but I do think that in its current form it is too broad and amounts to the OP asking for a lesson or a wikipedia entry, rather than the answer to a particular question

Answer (score 13):

It need not be differentiable everywhere. Let $P$ and $Q$ be mutually orthogonal self-adjoint projections. Then the norm of $P+ t Q$ is 1 for $|t| \leq 1$ and $|t|$ for $|t| > 1$.

However, $\|A + tB\|$ is Lipschitz in $t$, so it is differentiable almost everywhere by Rademacher's theorem.

Comment: Yes. I can see that. But what I meant is that do we know some nontrivial things, e.g. if it is k times differentiable or not etc.

Comment: Or $A=0$, $B=1$, so $f(t)=|t|$.

Comment: @SamyaRay It is not fair to ask for people to write down "some nontrivial things" because you are essentially asking other people to do the work of figuring out what questions you have.

Comment: Moreover, why do you have two separate accounts? It would be best if you ask the moderators to merge them

Comment: Okay. I understand. I wrongly commented at he place where I should have not.